# Removing .php and .html from URL

Tags: server, apache2, php

How can I remove `.php` and `.html` from my URLs?

So instead of it being `domain.com/about.php` it should be `domain.com/about`.

I used the same `.htaccess` code on my web hosting with OVH but since buying a VPS and doing it myself, it's not working. I just get a 404 error

> The requested URL /about was not found on this server.

I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
DirectorySlash On
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Each of the stanzas has the following logic:

1. If the requested file does not have an extension, that is, it does not match `\.[^./]+)$`, *and*
2. The requested file is not a directory, *and*
3. The requested file does not exist, *and*
4. There exists a file with the requested name and the extension `.html` (or `.htm`, or `.php`), *then*
5. Serve that file.

The `[L]` means last or final: no more rewriting is to be done, so the server can safely skip the rest of the rewrite rules.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me I dont get it.